# how to create an array with 3 students and have them sorted by firstname and nid

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need help with Create an object "student" with 3 properties: First name, last name, NID (5-digit number).

Create an array "myclass" with 3 students.

sort myclass with Firstname.

sort myclass with NID.

I have some of it set up but I don't know much about arrays and objects.  Need help doing it the proper way and explained

```js
var student = (firstname, lastname, nid) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.nid = nid;
  this.myclass = myclass;
}

var myclass = {
  "myclass": {
    student.firstname: "Matthew",
    student.lastname: "Stone",
    student.nid: 458293
  },

  "myclass": {
    student.firstname: "Arian",
    student.lastname: "Minaie",
    student.nid: 891023
  },

  "myclass": {
    student.firstname: "Pelin",
    student.lastname: "Schvechsky",
    student.nid: 496054
  }

}

function myFunction1() {
  myclass.sort();
  document.getElementById("Post").innerHTML = firstname;
}

function myFunction2() {
  myclass.sort();
  document.getElementById("Post").innerHTML = nid;
}
```

```html
<p id="Post"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Sort Alphabetically by First Name!</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Sort Numerically by NID!</button>
```

Comment: that produces a syntax error - fix those before asking

Comment: You need to 1: add a `</script>` tag to your page and then fix this: `var student = (firstname, lastname, nid) {` it is not correct syntax, you miss a `function` - Also a good idea to use `type="button"`on your buttons. I created a snippet for you so we can test your code immediately

Comment: Thanks I will try and fix that.  Sorry.  Not just javascript friendly

Comment: This is what I have so far.  I don't know how to set up the format to make 3 students fill the array and then sort them with the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a constructor for a student and create new instances for your students. Then you need to sort the array by the wanted properties.

```js
function Student(firstname, lastname, nid) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.nid = nid;
}

function sortByFirstnameAsc() {
    myClass.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname);
    });
    document.getElementById("Post").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myClass, 0, 4);
}

function sortByNIDAsc() {
    myClass.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.nid - b.nid;
    });
    document.getElementById("Post").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myClass, 0, 4);
}

var myClass = [
        new Student("Matthew", "Stone", 458293),
        new Student("Arian", "Minaie", 891023),
        new Student("Pelin", "Schvechsky", 496054)
    ];
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByFirstnameAsc()">Sort Alphabetically by First Name!</button>
<button onclick="sortByNIDAsc()">Sort Numerically by NID!</button>
<pre id="Post"></pre>
```